# Regex to allow only alphabets a to z and special characters ( ' , -) and another one with only alphabets,digits and special characters (. , - #)

Tags: jquery, regex, regex-negation

I want Basically two regex

1. allow only alphabets a-z and special characters ' and -
   tried this for it

   ```
       var specialCharRegex = ""

       specialCharRegex = /[a-zA-Z'-]/;

       var s_txtBox = this.value;
       if (s_txtBox != "") {
           debugger;
           if (specialCharRegex.test(s_txtBox)) {                    
               this.focus();                    
               return false;
           }                
       }
   ```
2. allow only alphabets a-z , digits 0-9 and special character . , - #

   tried this for it

   ```
       var specialCharRegex = ""

       specialCharRegex = /^[A-Za-z\d.#-,]$/;
       var s_txtBox = this.value;
       if (s_txtBox != "") {
           debugger;
           if (specialCharRegex.test(s_txtBox)) {
               debugger;
               this.focus();
               return false;
           }
       }
   ```

Cuurently not working well. Please help me in making these regexes.

Next thing i want to do is to replace unwanted characters from a string (my texbox) with empty string.
I am trying

```
this.value = this.value.replace(eval(specialCharRegex),'')  

this.value = this.value.replace(eval(/^[A-Za-z\d.#-,]$/),'')  

this.value = this.value.replace(eval(!/^[A-Za-z\d.#-,]$/),'')
```

but nothing worked. can you guys please sujjest what i should do?

Comment: 1) `/[a-zA-Z'-]/` -> `/^[a-zA-Z'-]*$/`, 2) `/^[A-Za-z\d.#-,]$/` -> `/^[A-Za-z\d.#,-]*$/`

Comment: Note that when you want to add a literal `-`  to a regex character class, you need to avoid making a range.  `a-z` and `A-Z` are ranges.  In your regex, `#-,` is likely a range as well.  This will probably cause undesirable side effects.  You need to either place the `-`elsewhere or escape it with a \.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - Does putting `-` at the end of the character class prevent it from needing to be escaped?

Comment: @zzxyz Yes, in almost all regex flavors. Put it at the character class start - and it will always be parsed as  a literal `-` in all regex flavors.

Answer (score 1):

you are just missing few things
 for the first one use:

```
var specialCharRegex=/^[a-zA-Z'-]+$/
```

for the second use:

```
var specialCharRegex=/^[a-zA-Z0-9.,#-]+$/
```